# Access violation reading location fprintf

Tags: c++, keyboard, char, int, printf

So here is what the teacher asked us to do:

Create a file that store what the user is typing. The trouble im having is that and exception is thrown and no error is given to me.  The first problem is the characters inside the text file are by default in CAPS (without the caps verification). The second The error happens as soon as i press a key (if theres a cap verification).

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

//function that write to the file
int Save(int _key, char *file, bool caps);
int Backspace();
bool caps = false;

int main() {
    char i;

    while (true) {
        for (i = 8; i <= 255; i++) {
            // Checks if a key is currently up or down
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
                //Get caps lock state
                if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
                    //Caps lock is on
                    caps = true;
                    Save(i, "C:/users/myComputer/documents/school/c++/input.txt", caps);
                }
                else {
                    //Caps lock is off
                    caps = false;
                    Save(i, "C:/users/myComputer/documents/school/c++/input.txt", caps);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int Save(int _key, char *file, bool caps) {
    Sleep(10);
    FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
    OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

 switch (_key) {

     case VK_RETURN:
         OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
         fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "\n");
         break;

     case VK_LBUTTON || VK_RBUTTON:
         OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
         fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "");
         break;

     default:
         if (caps == true) {
             char i = tolower(putchar(_key));
             OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
             fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", i);
         }
         else {
             char i = toupper(putchar(_key));
             OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
             fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", i);
         }
 }
 fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running this via command line? The program just ends? Are you sure there *is* an error?  If `if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)` never evaluates to true then your program will quit pretty quick without printing anything to console.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but are you allowed to `fopen` the same file twice? It looks like your `Save` function opens the file at the start, and then again in each branch.

Comment: @dckuehn yeah via the debugger in visual studio. Visual studio ask me to put a break. It was working great before i was trying yo implement the CapsLock feature.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser shouldnt be cause my variable just get overwrited. But its redundent indeed i need to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Segmentation fault**

There are several problems with this code.  But the main issue, causing the segmentation error is

```
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", i);   // Ouch !!!
```

`"%s"` tells `fprintf()` that it will find as argument a pointer to an array of characters.  Cross-check your format string [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).  Unfortunately, you provide an integer between 8 and 255.  This causes undefined behavior.

To correct the error change it to:

```
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%c", i);
```

**Other issues**

The `fopen()` call inside the `switch` is redundant: the file was already opened before.  It's no use to open a file without having closed it before.

The function documentation tells about least and most significant bit, but nothing about the bits in-between.  So the check should be:

```
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000 )   // but not strict equality
```